# What methods are available to disable drones besides EMP gadgets?

Tags: invisible-inc

You can disable drones with EMP [gadgets](http://invisibleinc.wikia.com/wiki/Gadgets), and also with Dr. Xu's default EMP augment.

However, in one of my campaign playthroughs, I noticed that a Shock Trap that had been triggered on a door by a guard also seemed to disable a nearby drone as well.

Is it really possible to disable drones with other gadgets that have a "shock" effect? What about other gadgets and augments that KO guards, such as the [HoloCircuit Overloader](http://invisibleinc.wikia.com/wiki/Augments) augment, which has a "shock" animation to it?

Comment: there is a [**discussion**](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/40198-dealing-with-drones/) about how to deal with drones

Comment: Camera drones and Obake Drone v2.0 are affected by tasers.
Other drones are KO immune.

This Wiki [here](http://invisibleinc.wikia.com/wiki/Enemies) shows drones vulnerabilities.

Comment: isn't this question answered already because vianna77 just answered it in the comments by giving the wiki link. I think you should close the question or self answer it

Answer (score -1):

Yes drones can be taken out with the shock effect. I'm also quite sure that upgraded weaponry can stun them (not quite 100% on that though)

You can read more about it here http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/40198-dealing-with-drones/